# Warning Message using the -e operator as the condition of a WHILE loop

Tags: perl

Using warnings and strict.  ActivePerl (vendor restricted) version 5.8.0 Build 806

Getting this warning message: Use of uninitialized value in numeric ne (!=) at D:\NIGHTLY\SamJudNighlty_ABS.pl line 589 (code snippet at bottom).

Actually multiple lines receive this warning as this construct is used frequently in the code.  Inherited this code and just trying to clean it up.  Not sure if this is an issue, but wanted to follow up on it.

From what I have researched: "-e returns 1 for true and '' for false, or the undefined value if the file doesn't exist.

```
587 $finFlag = $NightlyFlagPath . "\\FIN\\DONE";
588        
589 while((-e  $finFlag) != 1)
590 {
591   sleep(120);
592   print(PROGRESSFILE "\nWaiting for the Fin Nightly to finish" . getPCTime5()); 
593 }
```

Comment: You're correct, and warning pops as `undef` value is compared to `1`. Since such construct doesn't make sense, you can `until (-e  $finFlag) {..}` or what @zdim wrote.

Comment: `-e` returns a true value if the file exists, and `undef` if an error occurred (incl the file not existing).

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of "true/false" return of many operators in Perl, `-e` certainly included, is that it need not be tested any further.  You just need

```
while (not -e $finFlag) { ... }
```

---

The `!=` [equality operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators) compares its arguments *numerically* thus the warning when it gets `undef` to work with (or `''`, or any string). Which is precisely what happens when the file does not exist since `-e` then indeed returns `undef`, like other filetests do.

Answer (score 0):

`-e` returns a true value if the file exists, and `undef` if an error occurred (incl the file not existing).

You are using `undef` in a numerical comparison, thus the warning. Use boolean arithmetic instead.

Fixed:

```
while (!-e $finFlag) {
    sleep(120);
    print(PROGRESSFILE "Waiting for the Fin Nightly to finish " . getPCTime5() . "\n"); 
}
```

However, that will loop forever if the file exists, but something prevents you from getting information about it (such as a permission problem). The following solves that problem:

```
while (1) {
    last if -e $finFlag;
    die("Can't stat \"$finFlag\": $!\n") if !$!{ENOENT};

    sleep(120);
    print(PROGRESSFILE "Waiting for the Fin Nightly to finish " . getPCTime5() . "\n"); 
}
```

Slightly clearer:

```
while (1) {
    last if stat($finFlag);
    die("Can't stat \"$finFlag\": $!\n") if !$!{ENOENT};

    sleep(120);
    print(PROGRESSFILE "Waiting for the Fin Nightly to finish " . getPCTime5() . "\n"); 
}
```